# Why this simple htaccess rule does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi guys i did a rule :

```
RewriteRule ^actualite/    actualite.php   [L,NC]
```

but i want to have this  website/actualites/ it doesn't work.. and works only website/actualite/

Why this rule doesn't work ? `RewriteRule ^actualites/    actualite.php   [L,NC]`

Thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule with `MultiViews` turned off and optional `s` after `actualites`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^actualites?/ actualite.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.